# Set File Open path

Tags: javascript, php, file

In PHP, `fopen` Want To Set File Access Path

`$path = fopen('test.txt'); //basic format`

But, I want to set

`$path = fopen('/var/tmp/test.txt');`

Comment: *I want to set* - and what is the problem?

Comment: You can use full paths in `fopen()`.

Comment: *I want to set -*  You can set as you needed. `PHP` doesn't stop you :D